# Swift UIView Animations

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uiviewanimationtransition

Hi I have a basic View Controller with an ADD button on the right side of the navigation bar and I have UIView which is called Add View. The UIView is a small window that shows up when the ADD button is pressed. When the Add View shows up, I'm trying to add some kinda of animation. I have no idea on how to go about doing that. I included a picture of my storyboard. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

[image: This is basically what my storyboard looks like.]

Answer (score 0):

Use [this method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:), in options of type `UIViewAnimationOptions` there is a constant value of `ShowHideTransitionViews`

If you're new to animation, feel free to study this [Animation Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html), it tells you what you can animate and what can not, also depicting some methods example. [Ray Wenderlich's guide](https://www.raywenderlich.com/76200/basic-uiview-animation-swift-tutorial) is helpful too